# Output stream doesn't print anything

Tags: java, outputstream, printwriter

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter outputStream= null;
        try
        {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("text.txt")));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        finally {
                if (outputStream!= null)
                    outputStream.close(); 
        }


        outputStream.println("Hahahahaha");



    }
}
```

So I was given this sample code, but strangely it doesn't work at all, because when I open the text file. It's completely blank. How's that possible? Is it because of the output.close? I commented that part out, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Where is `outputStream` declared? Do you mean `output`? Also, if you close it, you can't write to it anymore.

Comment: yeah, i've been wondering about that... it doesn't make sense, but why would someone give me this as a demo code?

Answer (score 0):

Why use:

outputStream = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("text.txt")));

Why not just use:

PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter("text.txt");

Comment: I think it's a bad sample. I'm sure there are plenty of Java tutorials on how to write to a file! Perhaps you can check this one out:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Write your println statement before closing the stream

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try
        {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("text.txt")));
        outputStream.println("Hahahahaha");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        finally {
                if (outputStream != null)
                    outputStream.close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing `outputStream` before writing to it.

Note that the `finally` block **always executes when the try block exits**.
So you have to write to `outputStream` before exiting the `try` block.

Close it and you'll see the text you entered.

```
try
{
    outputStream = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("text.txt")));
    outputStream.println("Hahahahaha");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error");
    System.exit(0);
}
finally {
    if(outputStream != null)
       outputStream.close();
}
```